# Pass GET parameter and resultset to a servlet in Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to pass two values to a servlet from a jsp page. 1- a result set value, 2- a get parameter value.

It should look something like this in jsp page:

```
SCcalculator.getValue(rs.getString("value1"),request.getParameter("value1"));
```

on the servlet side how can i receive and manipulate this data in the `SCcalculator` package? any suggestions please?

Comment: have you tried `request.getParameter("value1")` ?

Comment: i dont understand how can i define a function in servlet. `getValue(?,?)` what would u replace the question marks with?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29

Follow this link

Answer (score 1):

In your servlet class use :

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        String s = request.getParameter("value1");
        String s1 = request.getParameter("value");
}
```

in JSP don't do like that, instead do :

```
<form action="name" method="post"> //here action=name is name of your servlet class name
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="text" name="value1">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">       
</form>
```

Comment: Try this, if get problem post me.

Comment: i can not use a form here. I simply need to calculate a value using a function. For this a user has to press submit and i want that done automatically.

Comment: But you can pass it to servlet and there you can calculate it. Or one way is that calculate it in JavaScript and post from there to servlet.

Comment: I did something like this on servlet: `public static double getSC(String a, String b)` Both the values were strings and i didnt know what type i should accept them as in servlet. Yes, i could use form but that isn't what a user would want to do ofcourse. +1 for the help. Appreciated :)

Comment: Have you use `document.location.href="/servletname?param=val"` ? in JavaScript ? you can calculate data in JavaScript and pass control to servlet like above.

Comment: If you still want to use Java Code in `JSP` then use `scriplet` and then send as `String` and in servlet parse as `double` or whatever type you want.

Comment: User i'm actually NOT PASSING VALUES to another page. I am merely trying to calculate some value using the already available values i have. And i came to know that using servlets is much better than using scriplets. Thats why i made a new servlet passed the values and now calculating the result.

Comment: Yes that's the better way, if any time JSP page crashes it's code will be shown to all, so always code at servlet side. :)

Comment: Actually i had to do the same procedure around 15 times on the same page. i considered calling a fucntion rather than scriplets that would make life easier by calling only. Thanks user :)

Comment: Yes you can call that servlet's function in JSP page, you just have to import the servlet class in your JSP page in header. My pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Conside this example

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo application</title></head>
<body>

<form id = "form1" method = "GET" action = "../Sample Application">
link1 : <input type = "text" id = "nRequests" name = "nRequests" />         
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit"/>

</form></body></html>
```

Now how you servlet will accept the request

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    nRequests = request.getParameter("nRequests");
```

In this way you can get the value from a HTML page to your servlets.